# Display "Loading" in windows Phone 8 sdk

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Just getting into the Windows phone 8 sdk.
Tried to find some books today without success.

I would like to create a simple Display Loading anymation (as you have when loading an app) while my SOAP request tries to download data.

I am unable to find something on the web...
I am programming in c# not JavaScript.

Anyone has some links to some good tutorials, references?

thank you

Comment: Have you seen the Progress Bar? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/hh202917(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: thank you very much! I see the prgoressbar like this does the trick :) <ProgressBar x:Name="pg2" Margin="10" Height="15" IsIndeterminate="True" /> thanks for the hint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [Progress Bar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/hh202917%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> A ProgressBar control shows the progress of an operation that has a
>   known duration, or shows that an indeterminate operation is in
>   progress.

And here is an [example](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2011/11/15/31-days-of-mango-day-15-the-progress-bar/) of using it.